# How to create a sdcardbootabble image for iMX8M

Tags: image

I am trying to create a sdcard image file for iMX8MQ.

The uboot non partitioned space would be 8M, followed by a ext4 rootfs

The process I go is:
create a file large as 8M+rootfs size, eg 1.3G

```
      DISK_PART=1360003072
      DISK_START=8388608
      DISK_WHOLE=$((DISK_PART+DISK_START))
      DSECTS=$((DISK_WHOLE/8192)) 
      dd if=/dev/zero of=./disk bs=8192 count=$DSECTS
```

fdisk the file and
add dos partition flag 'o'
first partiton 8M       from 2022- to 16384 sector
second partition 1.3G   from 16385 - to end sector

verify

```
fdisk -l disk
Disk disk: 1.27 GiB, 1368391680 bytes, 2672640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x547cf317

Device Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
disk1        2048   16384   14337    7M 83 Linux
disk2       16385 2672639 2656255  1.3G 83 Linux
```

split the file in 2 files 8m + 1.3G
./boot - 8M
./part - 1.3G-8M

format part side

`mkfs.ext4 ./part -L rootfs`

burn the uboot in boot file

`dd if=./flash.bin of=./boot bs=1024 seek=33`

combine them back
`cat ./boot ./part \> ./newdisk`

verify length

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    8388608 Jun 28 13:37 boot
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1368391680 Jun 28 13:33 disk
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user       4096 Jun 28 13:31 mnt
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1368391680 Jun 28 13:43 newdisk
```

check with fdisk

```
fdisk -l ./newdisk 
Disk ./newdisk: 1.27 GiB, 1368391680 bytes, 2672640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x547cf317

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
./newdisk1       2048   16384   14337    7M 83 Linux
./newdisk2      16385 2672639 2656255  1.3G 83 Linux
```

mount partition form file to ./mnt and deploy root fs

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=$((16384*512)) ./newdisk ./mnt
sudo tar -C ./mnt -x -f ../output/images/rootfs.tar
```

check them, then umount

```
ls ./mnt/
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  libexec  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var


sudo umount ./mnt

####  check again #######

fdisk -l ./newdisk 
Disk ./newdisk: 1.27 GiB, 1368391680 bytes, 2672640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x547cf317

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
./newdisk1       2048   16384   14337    7M 83 Linux
./newdisk2      16385 2672639 2656255  1.3G 83 Linux
```

Now dd on the sdcard

` sudo dd if=./newdisk of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=8M'

[The disk looks like this, Uboot cannot find image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUCWd.png)

What is wrong in what I am doing.
Thank you

What is wrong in creating a image file, at what point the partition table is lost.